Efficient nested parallelism
I am transitioning to parallel STL from my own thread pool. One thing in need is efficient nested parallelism. Consider the following code
std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, begin, end, f(i));

where f() may have the following definition:
void f(auto i)
{
  std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, 
    i->begin(), i->end(), g(j));
}

The above is probably inefficient in most cases due to nested parallelism.
To improve it, I intend to wrap for_each() and many other parallel STL algorithms (reduce(), transform_reduce(), any_of()...) in some fashion similar to the following:
namespace tp {

bool isInParaEnv = false;
int maxThread = tbb::this_task_arena::max_concurrency();
/* some other control variables... */

struct activate
{
  activate(int maxCore = tbb::this_task_arena::max_concurrency())
  {
    maxThread = std::max(1, std::min(
      maxCore, tbb::this_task_arena::max_concurrency()));
    isInParaEnv = false;
    /* some code... */
  }
  ~activate() { /* some code... */ }
};

void for_each(auto begin, auto end, auto && f)
{
  if (maxThread == 1 or isInParaEnv or std::next(begin) == end) 
  { 
    std::for_each(begin, end, f);
    return; 
  }
  isInParaEnv = true;
  std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, begin, end, f);
  isInParaEnv = false;
}
}

This allows me to be somewhat "oblivious" about nested parallelism using a unified loop interface. For example, f() can now be written as:
void f(auto i)
{
  /* some code... */
  tp::for_each(i->begin, i->end, [](auto j)->void {/* some code... */});
  /* some code... */
}

And the exported API can be as simple as:
int api()
{
  tp::activate();
  /* Some code... */
  tp::for_each(begin, end, f);
  /* Some code... */
}

However, the above design still has some shortcomings. For instance, if the machine has 16 threads and if the outermost loop takes only 2 iterations (begin + 2 == end), any inner loop will not invoke the parallel algorithm, and thus the parallel efficiency will be 2 at most.
How to improve the above design, hopefully without canceling the usage of parallel STL, so that we can be "oblivious" about nested parallelism while entertaining as many as possible but no more than std::thread::max_concurrency() threads during the run?
Thanks!

How much overhead does it have if you use a parallel execution policy in the inner loops as well?

@TedLyngmo The most recent one is about 2.7x slower for a 2-level loop

Ouch, ok, that was worse than I thought.

@TedLyngmo And to be more specific, -O3 is about 1.5x slower, -Ofast shoots up to 2.7x. Using GCC.

Ok, what about checking if you've parallelized < hardware_concurrency()? example

For such a use-case, I advise you to use OpenMP instead (which is included in all mainstream compiler). It had the same problem and fixed it with tasks (especially the #pragma omp taskloop directive). The OpenMP model is not only more flexible, but also more efficient in many cases. The STL uses a model which is known not to scale since few decades. The democratisation of big-little and many-core CPUs will make that even worse. OpenMP tasks can help not only for nesting but also in this case (though they are not great for memory bound operation on NUMA systems unfortunately).

The STL is still interesting/better for high-level operations like std::sort/std::stable_sort which are not easy to do in OpenMP assuming nesting is not needed (ie. this is not run in a parallel for or similar operations). This nesting problem is a (well-known) mess for parallel code composition in large applications and libraries.

@TedLyngmo thanks! I assume that could lead some kind of “over registration”? If there is 1 “free” thread left and another parallel foreach is executed, oversaturation  can still happen? Is STL foreach aware of the current threads running and going to only use the idle threads? Thanks!

@JérômeRichard thanks I was once an open no user but would like to stick to STL here. Algorithms like parallel sorting is a major reason for me to switch to pstl and to keep things unified.. I spent a lot of time crafting my own parallel sorting using a variety of algos and the best is still 1.8x slower than pstl sort..

@user2961927 Re "overregistration" - Yes, one would have to choose either or, or check how many tasks there are in the range and come uo with a clever formyla.

@TedLyngmo Thank you. After some searching and reading, I guess there's no super easy way out. A quick question about your solution: is there a particular reason for using mutex lock? Replacing it with some atomic integer operations is still OK right? If you'd like, please post your comment as an answer and i'll accept it

No, it's not very clear how one should go about limiting the number of threads in nested loops in a good way in a generic solution. I've always done it manually. I wanted the value of m_running to not change between the check running < hwc and running += m_tasks, so that's why I used a mutex. Otherwise, two threads may evaluate running < hwc as false and a lot more tasks than the hardware can handle efficiently. I'm not sure about my idea - I'll have to think about if I really want that as an answer. I'd like a better solution to this myself so perhaps it's best to leave the Q open.

@TedLyngmo Got it. Thanks!

I understand. It is indeed hard to make a sort faster than the one of the STL for generic use-case. The TBB implementation AFAIK use an SIMD-friendly sort which is particularly good. It might be the source of the speed up. If so, then you can use the STL sort in OpenMP tasks and then a merge the result. It is not as simple as using parallel STL though.
